# Getting 500 internal server error in Wix

Tags: jquery, html, velo

Where Can i post the sites i want to access in the code? For example, when i submit google, i then want to be sent to that site.

```
    <div>

  <H1><FONT="TIMES ROMAN" FONT-COLOR="BLUE" > SELECT An subject:</H1>

  <select id ="dropDownId"> <!-- give an id to select box-->

      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="Google">Google</option>
      <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
      <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>

  </select>
  <br>
  <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="SUBMITBUTTON"  value="Submit" style="font-size:20px; " />
</div>
<script src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery library-->
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.SubmitButton').click(function(){ // on submit button click

    var urldata = $('#dropDownId :selected').val(); // get the selected  option value
    window.open("http://"+urldata+".html") // open a new window. here you need to change the url according to your wish.
});
```

Comment: A 500 error is a server issue, so it's not directly to do with the HTML/JS you've shown. At what point do you get that error? I assume when you submit the form? If so, check the server logs (assuming you have some) to find the error message in order to debug this. At the moment there's not enough information here to help you

Comment: Also note that `links` will be a string, so looping over that isn't going to work in the manner you seem to expect (which would appear to be an array). In addition, you're trying to open browser windows in a loop, which will not work. Modern browsers have security features which stop scripts from spamming the user with multiple useless windows/tabs in this manner. I'd suggest finding another method to do what you require - such as modals.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you help me figure out the revised code